# How to change the title to H2 tag

Tags: javascript, extjs

I have a page which renders dynamic title. When I change the title to h2 using HeaderCfg, it is nesting elements in a span tag as follows

```
<h2 class=" x-unselectable">
  <span class="x-panel-header-text">This is Title</span>
</h2>
```

Expected:

```
<h2 class=" x-unselectable x-panel-header-text">This is Title</h2>
```

Code:

```
myForm = new Ext.FormPanel({
    title : Orginal.orginalTitle.get('get-title'),
    headerCfg: {
                tag: 'h2',
                },
    id : 'title-field',
});
```

VERSION: 3.4.0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can initially set the title to:

```
title: '<h2>mytitle</h2>'
```

In combination with an override for Panel:

```
        setTitle : function(title, iconCls){
            title = `<h2>${title}</h2>`;

            this.title = title;
            if(this.header && this.headerAsText){
                this.header.child('span').update(title);
            }
            if(iconCls){
                this.setIconClass(iconCls);
            }
            this.fireEvent('titlechange', this, title);
            return this;
        }
```